# Readable display of the filename using python

Tags: python, csv, filenames, readability

I am using the code below to extract the file names from a directory and print them. However, the print is not easilly readable and I was wondering if anyone could help me think of a better way to display it by seperating it.
 So my question is how would you seperate this file name using python?

```
from os import listdir

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]


filenames = find_csv_filenames('C:\Users\AClayton\Aug')
for name in filenames:
    print name
```

Which gives the filename `Agusta_AW149_Ground_2011_7_29_14_50_0.csv`.

I would like it to read something like `Name=Augusta Test=Ground  Date =29/7/2011`. I would like to do this for many file names which have the same format/order, just the 'Test' so the 'Ground' will change and the Date.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that every filename will have that attribute order, you can use

```
name.split('_')
```

and just organize the new strings as you prefer.
For instance, in your case you could do something like:

```
sep_names = name.split('_')
Name = 'Name='+sep_names[0]
Test = 'Test='+sep_names[2]
Data = 'Date='+sep_names[5]+'/'+sep_names[4]+'/'+sep_names[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string using `name.split('_')`, which would return a list in the following  format:

```
>>['Agusta', 'AW149', 'Ground', '2011', '7', '29', '14', '50', '0.csv']
```

Then you could print `name.split('_')[0]`, which would give you `Augusta`, etc.